# Outsource "network byte order" processing?

Tags: c++, networking, endianness

I'm using a number of sorf of `[Filter]` modules which "process data" and in the end write this data to different devices.

```
[Filter] -> [Filter] -> [Writer]
```

The Configuration is runtime dependent. The problem is in general the `[Filter]` doesn't really know it might be the end of the chain and where it's data is written to.

Some `[Filter]`s produce output in Google Protocol buffers, the `[Writer]` might be writing to a file. But in cases were structured data is produced and should be transmitted via network... like this:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct data_s {
    char a;
    int i;
    int j;
    char str[64];
};
#pragma pack(pop)
data_t d;
//...
d.i = htonl( d.i);
d.j = htonl( d.j);
this->write( d );
```

In this cases... is there a way to do this neither in every [Filter] nor in the [Writer]... the writer only sees a chunk of memory and nothing structured. Is there a way to do

```
[Filter] -> [Filter] -> [hton_struct] -> [Writer]
```

outsource the structured network byte order translation. Is there a comfortable and reusable way to transmit a chunk of memory with a translation description to network byte order? So one doesn't have to implement it in a `[Filter]` but a component which is only used if these precondition above apply?

Comment: If the filter chain is relatively dynamic, could you not just have a filter which does the hton, and insert that into the chain whenever it's required? After all, converting to network byte order is just processing the data.

Comment: Yes... that is more or less the idea. But how do I structure this, the  next filter will just see a chunk of memory? One would need some sort of description where to swap the endianess... and this can't be automatically computed but provided by the one writing this filter.